# C typedef pointing to a function[ c syntax]

Tags: c, syntax, function-pointers

So I normally program in java and Go so I'm sorry for my ignorance, I have learned basic c and c++. However when playing with JNI I came across this C code.

```
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, javaString, nativeString);
```

I was wondering why (*env) is pointing to a function. To my understanding env is just a struct and in C Functions are not dependent on a variable like how classes work in C++ and JAVA.

Am I missing something in C that allows functions only to fire for a struct?

Kind of like in Go

```
type House struct { }

func (h House) GetHouseName() string { } //method defined outside of struct, but works on House
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to word what I am looking for you Google hasn't really turned up much, and the books I ordered on C wont been in until next week.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are correct in noting that C functions do not carry an implicit scope or `this` object around. This is why you are having to explicitly pass `env` as the first parameter in the method call (in most OO languages this would happen implicitly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in your example `env` must be a pointer to a pointer-to-struct that contains a pointer to function (!).

Something like that:

```
struct MyEnvironment
{
    void (*ReleaseStringUTFChars)(MyEnvironment **env, /*...*/);
};

int main()
{
    MyEnvironment *theEnv = AllocEnvironment();

    MyEnvironment **env = &theEnv;

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, ...);
}
```

*(A few Google search later...)*

As it happens, in JNI there is that little typedef:

```
typedef const struct JNINativeInterface* JNIEnv;
```

And `env` is defined as:

```
JNIEnv *env;
```

Which effectively is a pointer-to-pointer-to-struct, as I guessed.

The problem with C functions is that they lack the concept of member functions, so they have to include an explicit argument to the object that invokes the function.

In JNI there is a weird precompiler trick to work both with C and C++ with the same header and same binary interface, but totally different syntax. For example, your C call:

```
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, javaString, nativeString);
```

In C++ would be:

```
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString, nativeString);
```

That will work because in C++ `env` is not a pointer-to-pointer, but a pointer to a type of this kind:

```
struct JNIEnv
{
    const struct JNINativeInterface* functions;

    /* inline function: no code generated */
    void ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstring string, const char* utf)
    {
        functions->ReleaseStringUTFChars(this, string, utf);
    }
    /* a lot of other functions... */
};
```

Since this class has a single member of type pointer-to-struct, it is binary compatible with such a pointer, that is can cast between a C++ `JNIEnv` and a C `struct JNINativeInterface *` without problem.

Answer (score 1):

`JNIEnv` (the type of `env`) is different for C and C++.

If you look at the source for JNI, you'll see something along these lines:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
typedef JNIEnv_ JNIEnv;
#else
typedef const struct JNINativeInterface_ *JNIEnv;
#endif
```

Looking at the C case first, we see that JNIEnv is a pointer to a struct containing a bunch of function pointers (I've only included a couple examples here):

```
struct JNINativeInterface_ {
    jclass (JNICALL *FindClass)(JNIEnv *env, const char *name);
    jfieldID (JNICALL *FromReflectedField)(JNIEnv *env, jobject field);
    // ...
}
```

So for C, `env` is a pointer to a struct of function pointers.  When you dereference `env` you get the struct, and then you dereference the function pointer to call the function.  This explains the `(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, javaString, nativeString);` line.

The C++ version uses a struct with member functions that wraps the `struct JNINativeInterface_`:

```
struct JNIEnv_ {
    const struct JNINativeInterface_ *functions;
    jclass FindClass(const char *name) {
        return functions->FindClass(this, name);
    }
}
```